# Is it possible to chain adding elements to each other in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to chain together DOM manipulation code so that it adds to the prior selector?

I've experimented with add() andSelf() etc etc, but can't seem to get anything to work:

Here is a rudimentary example I've put together, with some made up jquery code...

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

And I wanted to result in:

```
<ul>
    <li><p><span>Hello</span>alex</p></li>
    <li><p><span>Hello</span>alex</p></li>
    <li><p><span>Hello</span>alex</p></li>
</ul>
```

I'm wondering if there is a syntax similar to this (my jquery pseduo code):

```
$("li").prepend("<p>alex</p>").prepend("<span>Hello</span>");
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use prependTo:

```
$("<span>Hello</span>").prependTo("<p>alex</p>").prependTo("li");
```

Comment: Of course @Cybernate, thanks! I almost need to think backwards and outwards! For some reason when ever I need to do this in jquery I never seem to get it the right way around.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li').prepend($('<p>alex</p>').prepend($('<span>Hello</span>')));
```

- find the `<li`> item with `$('li')`
- to the `<li>` item prepend a new `<p>` element by creating it with `$('<p/>')`
- to that `<p>` element, prepend a `<span>` element by creating it with `$('<span/>')`

Comment: Thanks @Radu, good suggestion on the nesting sort of approach.